# PowerShell 7 "Get-Package" command returns NOTHING as result. PowerShell 5 RETURNS list of packages on the same computer

Tags: powershell

I have many packages on my lap top. I have preinstalled PS 5 and installed PS 7.
I install many software packages using the scripts in PS 7.
If I run Get-Package command in PowerShell version 7 I am not getting anything as output.

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> Get-Package
PS C:\Windows\System32>
```

If I run the same command in PowerShell 5 on the same computer I am getting many results:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-Package

Name                           Version          Source                           ProviderName
----                           -------          ------                           ------------

Git version 2.9.0              2.9.0                                             Programs
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (...                                                   Programs
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (...                                                   Programs
Office 16 Click-to-Run Exte... 16.0.11929.20606                                  msi
Office 16 Click-to-Run Loca... 16.0.11929.20606                                  msi
Office 16 Click-to-Run Lice... 16.0.11929.20606                                  msi
```

How is this possible??? Get-Command is the Windows command which should return result in any case. Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like newer Powershells don't support the Programs and Msi providers.  Not good.

```
Get-PackageProvider  # from Powershell 5

Name     Version DynamicOptions
----     ------- --------------
msi      3.0.0.0 AdditionalArguments
Programs 3.0.0.0 IncludeWindowsInstaller, IncludeSystemComponent
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Can you please provide me link where this is stated and exmapled?
By MSI I know on what you are reffering (msi packages for installation). But can you please explain me what do you exactly mean by "Programs"??? EXE files or software which are installed in "Program File" or what...? Sorry I did not understood.

Comment: You can see in your output which packages are the Programs provider.  They had .exe installers not msi ones.  There's an old issue filed about it here:  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7844  It seems like a pretty serious drawback to me.

Comment: My output for Get-PackageProvider (from PS 7) is following:

Name                     Version          DynamicOptions
----                     -------          --------------
NuGet                    3.0.0.1          Destination, ExcludeVersion, Scope, SkipDependencies, Headers, FilterOnTag, …



PowerShellGet            2.2.3.0          PackageManagementProvider, Type, Scope, AllowClobber, SkipPublisherCheck, In…

Comment: So what does it mean sorry I am not sure - that only PowerShellGet and NuGet are supported providers or that I am having currently some software installed from those providers?

Comment: Only those 2 are supported