# Get-Package - PS CORE no longer provides installed software

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powershell-core

I'm moving a yaml pipeline so it uses PS Core. One of the steps is to parse currently installed software and uninstall it if it exists:

```
    $appsToUninstall = Get-Package -Provider Programs -IncludeWindowsInstaller -name "*$Instance*"
    if ($appsToUninstall.count -gt 0)
    {
        Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "$Instance" } | Stop-Service
        $appsToUninstall | Uninstall-Package -Force -Verbose
        Write-Output "Uninstalled $Instance"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Warning "Nothing to uninstall! Could not locate $Instance as an installed instance. Continuing as usual."
    }
```

However, it would seem that the new Get-Package - no longer provides installed software.

[image: Doesntwork1]
[image: Doesntwork2]
[image: Works]

Is there any way to use native cmdlets (not CMI/WMI [wmi is deprecated!]) to achieve that in the new PS 7+?

Comment: Seems that it no longer supports what I want it to do...:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61466924/powershell-7-get-package-command-returns-nothing-as-result-powershell-5-retur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the registry to achieve this :

```
$Instance = "MyAppToUninstall"

# Initialize array to avoid errors on 32 bits applications addition
[array]$appsToUninstall = @()

# Get 64 bits programs
$appsToUninstall = Get-ItemProperty `
                   HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
                   Select DisplayName, UninstallString | 
                   Where { $_.DisplayName -like "*$Instance*" }

# Add 32 bits programs
$appsToUninstall += Get-ItemProperty `
                    HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
                    Select DisplayName, UninstallString | 
                    Where { $_.DisplayName -like "*$Instance*" }

if ($appsToUninstall.count -gt 0)
{
    Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "$Instance" } | Stop-Service
    $appsToUninstall | ForEach-Object {
        $app = $_.UninstallString.Substring(0, $_.UninstallString.IndexOf(".exe") + 4)
        $arguments = $_.UninstallString.Substring($_.Uninstallstring.IndexOf(".exe") + 5)
        if ($app -match "(?i)msiexec")
        {
            # if MSI package, replace /i parameter by /x to uninstall and
            # add /passive parameter to automate the uninstallation
            $arguments = "$($arguments.Replace("/I", "/x", [system.StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) /passive"
        }
        Start-Process -FilePath $app -ArgumentList $arguments
    }
    Write-Output "Uninstalled $Instance"
}
else
{
    Write-Warning "Nothing to uninstall! Could not locate $Instance as an installed instance. Continuing as usual."
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: +1 for a workable solution. Huge -1 to Microsoft for the fact that this level of hackery is necessary (especially when it's only necessary because they've broken their own tools and chosen not to fix them).